# How to use Page of Blacksmithing

Tags: diablo-iii

In nightmare I obtained two "Page of Blacksmithing". How do I use them on Haedrig?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66952/10260

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're ingredients for both crafting recipes and upgrading the blacksmith level. In either case, the blacksmith tab will show a Page of Blacksmithing (or other dropped ingredients) as a requirement for the action that requires a page. Just hold on to them until you get to that level.

Answer (score 3):

[Blacksmith Skill Progression](http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Blacksmith_Progression)

You won't need the pages till you level Haedrig up to Grandmaster level (after that it is 5 pages per level to finish Grandmaster & Illustrious training)